# Laravel Datatables order by relationship column does not work

Tags: php, laravel-5, datatables, eloquent, yajra-datatable

I have one `User` who can be assigned to many `Company`. I'm trying to render a table using Laravel Datatables & jQuery Datatables. It renders nicely and when clicking on the order icon in the table header, it sorts data by that column, except, it doesn't work for the relationship column `company_name`.
This is my code in the controller:

```
$users = User::with(['roles','companies'])
        ->where('users.id', '!=', Auth::id())
        ->whereHas('roles', function($q){$q->whereId(Role::ROLE_6);});
```

...

```
return Datatables::of($users)
->editColumn('company', function (User $user) {
                return $user->hasCompanies()? $user->companies->first()->company_name : trans('lang.company.not_assigned');
            })
->orderColumn('company', 'company')
->make(true);
```

And this is my javascript for datatables:

```
otable = $('#datatable_fixed').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    url: 'users/datatable',
                    type: 'POST',
                },
                "pageLength": 15,
                "processing": true,
                "stateSave": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "bDestroy": true,
                columns: [
                    {data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name'},
                    {data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name'},
                    {data: 'company', name: 'company.company_name'},
                    {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
                    {data: 'status', name: 'status'},
                ],
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                searching: false,
                "order": [[0, 'asc']],
                "autoWidth": true,
            });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a table called `rides` with multiple relationships with `drivers`, `customers`, `vehicles`, and `companies`. I needed one column that contains the concatenated value of two relationship table columns that can be sortable and searchable.

This query does the above work for me

```php
$rides = Ride::select(['rides.*', DB::raw('CONCAT(drivers.code," - ",drivers.name) AS driver')])
    ->with(['drivers','customers','vehicles','companies'])
    ->join('drivers','rides.driver_id','=', 'drivers.id');
```

After this I have added below code to this ajax method of loading the data table data.

```js
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    "processing":true,
    "serverSide":true,
    "ajax": "{{route('ajax.view.rides')}}",
    "columns": [
        {data: 'driver', name: 'driver', searchable:false},
        {data: 'drivers.code', name:'drivers.code', searchable: true, sortable : true, visible:false},
        {data: 'drivers.name', name:'drivers.name', searchable: true, sortable : true, visible:false},
       
    ],
    responsive:true,
    order:[0,'desc']
});
```

The concatenated column that we have added on our query make the sorting possible

```js
{data: 'driver', name: 'driver', searchable:false},
```

This column definition will make the searching possible with the both columns

```js
{data: 'drivers.code', name:'drivers.code', searchable: true, sortable : true, visible:false},
{data: 'drivers.name', name:'drivers.name', searchable: true, sortable : true, visible:false},
```

Now you need to add two extra `<th>` tags inside the HTML table thread element.

```html
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Driver</th> <!-- this one will display the concatenated column -->
    <th>Driver</th> <!-- this one is for the hidden hidden column that enables the search on one column -->
    <th>Driver</th> <!-- this one is for the hidden hidden column that enables the search on one column -->
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```php
$model = Expenses::with('employee')
    ->where('bookingoffice_id', Auth::user()->bookingoffice)
    ->where('capitalsmb.expenses.active', 1)
    ->select('expenses.*');
```

Comment: I faced an issue, adding  ```->select('expenses.*')``` will also create an N+1 problem which will start showing the same data multiple times, also mentioned in this comment,

https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/2623#issuecomment-827327299